# Properties of equality

Tags: relations

> Why is this relation transitive? $R = \{(x,y)\in\Bbb N^2\mid x + 4y = 10\}$

Comment: So you have the linear equation $y=-\frac14 x + \frac52$.  Maybe you can try visualizing it from there?

Comment: a cursory trial shows it's not reflexive.

Comment: The question was presented like this in the textbooks.. and then everything else is fine. I didn't understand how it is transitive.

Comment: The point is whenever you can find a $y$ such that $xRy$ and $yRz$, then all $x, y,z$ are forced to equal to $2$, so $xRz$ is also true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume x + 4y = 10 and y + 4z = 10.  Does x + 4z = 10?
Exercise.  Prove for x,y in N, x + 4y = 10, the solutions are
(2,2), (6,1).

Thus if aRb and bRc, then b = 2.
Whence a = b = c = 2, so aRc.

Comment: N is collection of Natural Numbers.. 0 does not exist in N..  So just because it is not having a (y,z) pair.. can lead a relation to be accepted as transitive?

Comment: @zion.  Nonsequiture.  See edit

Comment: Thanks understood...